# how to retrieve certificate from personal my store

Tags: java, servlets, x509certificate

I want to retrieve certificate with password from personal my store by java programming.
I found some code of retrieving certificate but it shows all certificates. These certificates shown data didn't need to open with these related password.
I do not want to these style of showing certificate. I want to write the code format type is-  choose certificate I want and I add password of this certificate on the browser and then show of this certificate information.

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    ks.load(null, null) ;
    Enumeration en = ks.aliases() ;
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String aliasKey = (String)en.nextElement() ;
        Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey) ;
        System.out.println("---> alias : " + aliasKey) ;
        if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliasKey)) {
            Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(aliasKey);
            System.out.println("---> chain length: " + chain.length);
            X509Certificate Cert = null;
            for (Certificate cert: chain) {
                System.out.println(cert);
            }
       }                
    }
```

How to repair this code? And I found some C# code for accessing certificate. I wanna also use just like this by java program. How to convert the following C# code to java code?

Access certificate by C#

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 X509Certificate2Collection col = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "{serial number no space}", true);
 //service is the webservice that need to //be authenticated using X509 certificate
 TestWebService service = new TestWebService();
//Note, we should find the certificate from the the 
//root certificate store on local machine if the
//certificate is imported correctly and the serial
//number is correct 
if (col.Count == 1)
 { 
  //all we need to do is to add the certificate 
  //after that we can use the webservice as usual

  service.ClientCertificates.Add(col[0]);
  service.Test();

 }
```

Comment: Too vague. Nobody is going to just rewrite your code for you. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to know that how to retrieve specific certificate with password from personal my store. This code is to get all certificate from my store but I want to get specific certificate that I want. So how to write program? Not matter that do not same my code.

Comment: I suggest you check the Javadoc. There are other ways of getting things out of a `KeyStore` than just iterating over its entire contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is not certificate specific. The password is for the keyestore. Its similar to the database where in the password is for a schema  and not individual tables.

To answer other question of retrieving on a single certificate, for that you would need to know the alias beforehand and use that alias to retrieve the certificate.

in your code it would be `ks.getCertifcate("alias")`

Comment: Individual keystore entries can have a password.

Comment: Can you posts some links regarding this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getKey(java.lang.String,%20char[])

Comment: The link you have posted does not have anything to show that a `Certificate` retrieval from keystore needs password. All it shows that a `Private key` retrieval from keystore need password. Certificates and Private keys are not the same.

Comment: I didn't say it *needed* a password. I said it 'can have' a password. Which implies that 'the password is *not* [just] for the keystore'.

Comment: Agreed. But the response I posted was for was for `Certificate` (_which do not need password_) and _very specific_ to what OP is expecting.